# How to remember pending intents and alarms after the phone is rebooted?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-pendingintent, android-alarms, android-broadcast

I am really new to android, I have been making an app which turns the phone into the vibration mode according to my college time table. I want my app to remember the pending intents after the phone is restarted, so that the don't have to feed to their time table every time the device is rebooted.

Here's my code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Calendar;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlarmManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent; 
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CheckBox;


public class Labs extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

private ArrayList <Calendar> Cal= new ArrayList <Calendar>(60);

private ArrayList <CheckBox> l= new ArrayList <CheckBox>(60);

private ArrayList <Boolean> checkboxValue_lab = new ArrayList <Boolean>(60);

private SharedPreferences mSharedPreferences_l;
private SharedPreferences.Editor mPrefsEditor_l;
private Button submitButton;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_labs);
    addenable();


    submitButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    submitButton.setOnClickListener(this);

    mSharedPreferences_l = getSharedPreferences("loginPrefs", MODE_PRIVATE);
    mPrefsEditor_l = mSharedPreferences_l.edit();




    //Initialise check boxes for every slot
    for (int i = 101; i <= 160; i++) {
           String viewId = "checkBox" + i;
           l.add(i-101, (CheckBox) findViewById(getResources().getIdentifier(viewId, "id", getPackageName())));
           checkboxValue_lab.add(i-101, mSharedPreferences_l.getBoolean("lab"+(i-101), false));

           if (checkboxValue_lab.get(i-101) == true) {
               l.get(i-101).setChecked(true);}
           }
        }   



@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}   

public void addenable(){

}

public int Day(int a)
{
    int d=0;
    int x = a;
    x--;

    if(x>=30)
        d = (x/6)-3;

    else
        d=(x/6)+2;

    return d;
}

public int Hour(int a)
{
    int hr=0;
    int x=a;

    x--;

    hr=(x%6)+8;

    if((x%6)>=4)
        hr--;

    if(x>=30)
        hr = hr+6;

    return hr;

}

public int Min(int a)
{
    int m=0;
    int x=a;

    if(x%6==5)
        m=50;

    if(x%6==0)
        m=40;

    return m;
}

public void getdata(View V){

    for( int i=0; i<60; i++)
    {
        Cal.add(i, Calendar.getInstance());
        Cal.get(i).set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, Day(i+1));
        Cal.get(i).set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, Hour(i+1));
        Cal.get(i).set(Calendar.MINUTE, Min(i+1));
        Cal.get(i).set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    }


    //Intents
    Intent setVibration = new Intent();
    setVibration.setClass(this, AlarmReciever.class);



    //PENDING INTENTS
    ArrayList <PendingIntent> Lab_V= new ArrayList <PendingIntent>(60);


    for(int i=0; i<60; i++)
    {
        Lab_V.add(PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, i, setVibration,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT));

    }

    // create the object
    AlarmManager mAlarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

    for(int i=0; i<60; i++)
    {
            if(l.get(i).isChecked()){

             mAlarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, Cal.get(i).getTimeInMillis(), 7*24*60*60*1000, Lab_V.get(i));


            }
    }

    }


public void onClick(View view) {

    for(int i = 0; i < 60 ; i++){

        if(l.get(i).isChecked()){
            mPrefsEditor_l.putBoolean("lab"+i, true);
            mPrefsEditor_l.commit();
        }
        else {
            mPrefsEditor_l.putBoolean("lab"+i, false);
            mPrefsEditor_l.commit();
        }
    }

    getdata(view);

}
}
```

AlarmReciever.java

```
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class AlarmReciever extends BroadcastReceiver
{
private AudioManager mAudioManager;

@Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
        {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        mAudioManager = (AudioManager)context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
        mAudioManager.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_VIBRATE);

        // Show the toast
        Toast.makeText(context, "Vibration Mode", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

          }
}
```

Android Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="ish.k.silentmode"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

  <!-- permission required to use Alarm Manager -->
        <uses-permission android:name="com.android.alarm.permission.SET_ALARM"/>




<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >



    <activity
        android:name="ish.k.silentmode.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" 
       >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name="ish.k.silentmode.GetSlots"
        android:label="Select your slots"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >


    </activity>

     <activity
        android:name="ish.k.silentmode.MorningSlots"
        android:label="Select your morning slots"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >


    </activity>

      <activity
        android:name="ish.k.silentmode.EveningSlots"
        android:label="Select your evening slots"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >


    </activity>

       <activity
        android:name="ish.k.silentmode.Labs"
        android:label="Select your lab slots"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >


    </activity>

       <activity
        android:name="ish.k.silentmode.About"
        android:label="About"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >


    </activity>

     <activity
        android:name="ish.k.silentmode.AlarmReciever"
        android:label="AlarmReciever" >


    </activity>

       <!-- Register the Alarm Receiver -->
               <receiver android:name=".AlarmReciever"/>

      <activity
        android:name="ish.k.silentmode.RingerMode"
        android:label="RingerMode" >


    </activity>

       <!-- Register the Alarm Receiver -->
               <receiver android:name=".RingerMode"/>
</application>

</manifest>
```

Please help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set it again after system reboots, you can use a boot receiver for it.

It is described on Google developers [here](https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html#boot).

Basically this, define receiver on your AndroidManifest:

```
<receiver
    android:name=".BootReceiver"
    android:permission="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"
    android:enabled="true" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

And implement BootReceiver as an normal broadcast receiver.